# Usando o utilitário sysstat para salvar as informações de uso do servidor em formato XML

Tags: linha-de-comando, cron, linux

[Sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/features.html) permite coletar todas as informações que preciso do servidor:

uso de CPU, memórias, buffers...

sadf - com a opção -x imprime no formato XML.

Gostaria que todas as informações (uso de CPU, memórias, buffers) fossem salvas em formato XML a cada 2 minutos. Como posso fazer isso? Não estou conseguindo juntar todas as opções do sysstat para rodar com o cron.